# Git Commit not working in my Command prompt

Tags: git, github, deployment

every things was going good but when i enter the "git commit -m 'First Commit' " it does not work and showing this error

```
developer@developer-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/ajax (master)
$ git commit -am 'gjhgj'

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <(null)>) not allowed
```

Please somebody help in this regard

Answer (score 3):

You should set your email and name as specified in the error message by running

```
git config --global user.email "<you@example.com>"
git config --global user.name "<Your Name>"
```

You can omit --global if your want to set these information only for the current project.